# Get the body of an external website with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get the body of an external website. I got this working for another website using the querySelectorAll() method. However, the website I am trying to get the body from does not have any classes/id's (it's just some text). So far I came up with this:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == xml.DONE) {
        var container = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().documentElement;
        container.innerHTML = xml.responseText;
        var body = container.body.innerText;
        console.log(body);
    }
};
xhr.open("POST", artist_url);
xhr.send(null);
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange
```

What am I doing wrong / not understanding?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've to refer to `container.ownerDocument.body`, `container` is actually the `<html>` element (providing the response text contains a body tag). Notice also, that `onreadystatechange` fires multiple times during the AJAX request, check the `readyState` property (4) and the status (200), or use `onload`and check the status before trying to use the response.

Comment: ... and the AJAX call can success only when the source page has CORS headers enabled, otherwise a cross-origin request fails.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to refer to `container.ownerDocument.body`, container is actually the `<html>` element (providing the response text contains a body tag). Notice also, that `onreadystatechange` fires multiple times during the AJAX request, check the `readyState` property (4) and the status (200), or use `onload` and check the status before trying to use the response.

... and the AJAX call can success only when the source page has CORS headers enabled, otherwise a cross-origin request fails.

— [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu)